# Centering text on Input Form

Tags: php, css, html-table, center

I have scoured the Forum but can't find an answer to what is probably a simple question. I have a Form and can centre the text for the heading line but cannot centre text on subsequent "input" lines. I have tried to use CSS (though am not very proficient). The code is below. Can anyone help please?

```
$a = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");
$b = array("4","5","4","3","4","5","3","4","4","3");

$form = "<form method=\"post\">";  
$form .= "<table  border=\"1\"  cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"> ";
$form .= "<tr>";
$form .= "<td width = \"10\" align = \"center\">A</td> ";
$form .= "<td width = \"10\" align = \"center\">B</td> ";
$form .= "</tr>";

for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++)
{
    $form .= "<tr>";
    $val = "t_".$i;
    $val1 = $a[$i];
    $form .= "<td width = \"10\" align = \"center\"><input type=\"text\" ";
    $form .= "name=".$val." value = ".$val1." readonly></td> ";
    $val2 = "v_".$i;
    $val3 = $b[$i];
    $form .= "<td width=\"10\" align =\"center\"><input type=\"text\" ";
    $form .= "name=".$val2." value = ".$val3." readonly></td> ";
    $form .= "</tr>";
}

$form .= "</table>";
$form .= "</form>";
echo ($form);
```

Comment: `<td width="10" style="text-align:center"><input ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this -

```
$form.="<td width=\"10\" align =\"center\"><input type=\"text\" ";
$form.= "name=".$val2." value = ".$val3." readonly style='text-align: center;'></td> ";
```